# Getting Office 365 credentials in powershell without prompt

Tags: windows, azure, powershell, office365

i would like to automate downloading files from Sharepoint to local disc using powershell but i dont want my users to enter the password as script will run on each system startup.

Windows password is the same as password to Office 365 so i could use this one, any tips how can i achive that in PS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use DefaultNetworkCredentials

```
 $ctx=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl) 
 $ctx.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
 $web = $ctx.Web
 $ctx.Load($web);
 $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```